# From local scrapy to scrapy cloud (scraping hub) - Unexpected results

Tags: regex, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapinghub

The scraper I deployed on Scrapy cloud is producing an unexpected result  compared to the local version. 
My local version can easily extract every field of a [product item](https://www.zooplus.fr/shop/chiens/croquettes_chien/bozita_robur_croquettes_chien/chien_age/640111) (from an online retailer) but on the scrapy cloud, the field "ingredients" and the field "list of prices" are always displayed as empty. 
You'll see in a picture attached the two elements I'm always having empty as a result whereas it's perfectly working 
I'mu using Python 3 and the stack was configured with  a scrapy:1.3-py3 configuration. 
I thought first it was in a issue with the regex and unicode but seems not.
So i tried everything : ur, ur RE.ENCODE .... and didn't work.

For the ingredients part, my code is the following :

```
    data_box=response.xpath('//*[@id="ingredients"]').css('div.information__tab__content *::text').extract()
    data_inter=''.join(data_box).strip()

    match1=re.search(r'([Ii]ngr[ée]dients\s*\:{0,1})\s*(.*)\.*',data_inter)
    match2=re.search(r'([Cc]omposition\s*\:{0,1})\s*(.*)\.*',data_inter)


    if match1:
        result_matching_ingredients=match1.group(1,2)[1].replace('"','').replace(".","").replace(";",",").strip()

    elif match2 : 
        result_matching_ingredients=match2.group(1,2)[1].replace('"','').replace(".","").replace(";",",").strip()

    else:
        result_matching_ingredients=''

    ingredients=result_matching_ingredients
```

It seems that the matching never occurs on scrapy cloud.

For prices, my code is the following :

```
    list_prices=[]

    for package in list_packaging : 
        tonnage=package.css('div.product__varianttitle::text').extract_first().strip()
        prix_inter=(''.join(package.css('span.product__smallprice__text').re(r'\(\s*\d+\,\d*\s*€\s*\/\s*kg\)')))
        prix=prix_inter.replace("(","").replace(")","").replace("/","").replace("€","").replace("kg","").replace(",",".").strip()

        list_prices.append(prix)
```

That's the same story. Still empty.

I repeat : it's working fine on my local version. 
Those two data are the only one causing issue : i'm extracting a bunch of other data (with Regex too) with scrapy cloud and I'm very satisfied with it ?

Any ideas guys ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that Scrapping Hub’s logs are displaying the expected version of Python even if the stack is correctly set up in the project’s yml file.

Answer (score 1):

I work really often with ScrapingHub, and usually the way I do to debug is:

1. Check the **job requests** (through the ScrapingHub interface)

In order to check if there is not a redirection which makes the page slightly different, like a query string `?lang=en`

2. Check the **job logs** (through the ScrapingHub interface)

You can either print or use a logger to check everything you want trough your parser. So if you really want to be sure the scraper display the same on local machine and on ScrapingHub, you can `print(response.body)` and compare what might cause this difference.

If you can not find, I'll try to deploy a little spider on ScrapingHub and edit this post if I can manage to have some time left today !

Comment: Thansks for your input. Request seems ok. No language issue so far. 
One thing. I'm using python3 locally and whereas I used this in yml `stacks:
  default: scrapy:1.3-py3`the log is showing me a 2.7 setup. 
Concerning the response.body, it seems okay and comparable. We are just having an "encoding issue". Scrappy hub is displaying some unicode character but it shouldn't be a problem from regex.

Comment: Sewake would you have any other idea to solve this headaches giving issue ?

Comment: Mhh if you don't see anything strange in response.body right now I don't have many ideas... If we focus on the first field, what is output of `data_inter` ? Is it what you expect ?


The encoding issue could be the reason why, because of the `é` accent of `Ingrédient` and `€` special character of price field.

(Sorry I didn't had time to look in more detail)

Comment: Okay it was very simple. It was only the python 3.6 stack which wasn’t launching. It was no coding issue or scraping difficulty. Just the stack.